# back button in webview

Tags: iphone, webview

I have a `UITableView` and when an item is selected I load an `WebView` like this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[[nameCatalog objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"url"]];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    [webView setHidden:NO];
}
```

What I wanna do is implement a `BackButton` so when I'm on the webview I can come back to `UITableView.`

So I did this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[[nameCatalog objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"url"]];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
    [self.view addSubview:webView];
    [webView setHidden:NO];
    UIBarButtonItem *infoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                   initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(info_clicked:)];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = infoButton;
}

- (void) info_clicked:(id)sender {

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
    [webView removeFromSuperView];
    }
```

But when I load the `webview` there is no button appearing.!!!!!
Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because you are adding the webview as a subview, rather than pushing another viewController on the stack.

Also: the back button is configured by the title of the view controller. To change that to a back button you need to create a back button in the view before the view is pushed. I have two examples:

[BackButton.zip](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/585261/BackButton.zip) which shows how the back button is configured in the init method of a view controller.

[LoadWebViewTable.zip](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/585261/LoadWebViewTable.zip) which shows how the back button is configured in the `awakeFromNib` method. This example follows your app more closely I think.

The point is that the back button is configured in the view that it is returning to. Also, both examples use nil-targetted actions, so you don't even need to have a callback to pop the view off the stack - it comes for free.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that, put the web view in a different view controller and use

`[self.navigationController pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];`

instead of

`[self.view addSubview:webView];`

Comment: The button still doesn't appear

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should do some of this stuff in your interface.  Connect a table view to your code.  Have a button in your interface connected to an IBAction, hidden when you launch the app, then when your user clicks a table view cell, unhide the button.

Hope this helped!